# Visual Studio automatically closing DIV surrounding Legend

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html, legend, autoformatting

So I have a bit of code throughout my project,

```
 <fieldset>
        <div  class="legendContainerInactive">
            <legend>Legend Stuff
            </legend>
        </div>
 ....
 </fieldset>
```

Which allows me to have the top of my legend all pretty and full - basically a bar of color.  However, Visual Studio has decided that Legends can't be contained in divs.  Which might be a standard somewhere, but GOSH DARN IT, my code works like this and looks great on all browsers.

Everytime I save Visual Studio adds a closing div so it looks like this

```
 <fieldset>
        <div  class="legendContainerInactive">
        </div>
            <legend>Legend Stuff
            </legend>
        </div>
 ....
 </fieldset>
```

So my pages keep breaking because an extra div VS decided was SUPER important.  I've disabled VS from closing divs in the formatter, and stopped it from closing tags.  It keeps doing this.  ARGH! How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `<legend>` should not come under a `<div>` tag a `<legend>` must only be used under a `<fieldset>`, which itself is a child of `<form>` tag.

`Correct Syntax-Structure to use these will be somewhat like this:`

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend> … </legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So at first you shouldn’t be using it in this way and VS will keep correcting it BUT if you still want to use than:

- You can disable this auto-tag closing in `Options` > `Text Editor` > `HTML` > `Formatting` & Uncheck the box for `Auto insert close tag`.

However i will still suggest to play by the standard conventions and rules, You never know what the next browser update is going to bring for you..

See:

[HTML legend Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp)

[DTD (Document Type Definition)](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp)

Thankyou.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but I've already disabled the auto-tag closing and it is still doing this.  Seems like a different part of visual studio is getting in on this.

Comment: Do you have any additional plugins like `Resharper` installed?